# fread oddity -- only reading a small number of items

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, fread

In the middle of a rather large command line app that has been working.  Made some changes to handle files larger than I can buffer and encountering a strange result from `fread`.

```
DebugLog(@"Reading %d samples of a total %d samples of size %d, leaving %d samples remaining", numSamplesToRead, numSamplesInFile, sizeof(short) * channels * scaleFactor, numSamplesRemainingInFile);
DebugLog(@"Position in file is %d", ftell(in));
items = fread(dataBuffer, sizeof(short) * channels * scaleFactor, numSamplesToRead, in);
DebugLog(@"%d samples read", items);
DebugLog(@"Position in file is %d", ftell(in));
```

This results in the following output:

```
<main:(604)> Reading 29278208 samples of a total 115202048 samples of size 8, leaving 85923840 samples remaining
<main:(605)> Position in file is 512
<main:(607)> 448 samples read
<main:(608)> Position in file is 58560512
```

(The file in question is 225008K in size.)

So how can I read only 448 samples of 8 bytes each and move from position 512 to position 58560512?  Why isn't the requested amount of data being read?

Comment: I believe that `items` being less than `numSamplesToRead` indicates an error in the read. Does `errno` have a relevant value?

Comment: Hmmm... perror showing "Bad address", but the buffer address appears to be good, and I don't know what other address it would refer to.  ferror has a value of 1.

Comment: Lemme check that the buffer allocation is large enough.

Comment: OK, it looks like my buffer's too small by 2.  I was expecting a nasty crash in that case, I guess that the system is too smart for me.  (Put your comment in an answer and I'll credit it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `fread()` should be the same as the `nitems` argument (`numItemsToRead`, in your case). The fact that `items` and `numItemsToRead` are different indicates that something went wrong with the read, but since the file pointer has advanced past what has been read, maybe there's something wrong with your buffer?

You should check `errno` and/or `ferror()` to see if there's any relevant information.